# Where is ilasm.exe in Microsoft.NETCore.ILAsm?

Tags: .net-core, ilasm

I need the most recent ilasm.exe. I thought it would be the one from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.ILAsm/

However, the downloaded microsoft.netcore.ilasm.2.0.0.nupkg archive doesn't contain any .exe or .dll files.

I don't get how to use this package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This package makes use of a new feature in NuGet to split packages per runtime. At the root of the `Microsoft.NETCore.ILAsm` package, you'll find a `runtime.json` file that references other nuget packages per platform. This means that when this package is used for runtime-specific actions, another referenced one is used.

For 64 bit windows, this json file contains:

```
"win-x64": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.ILAsm": {
    "runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILAsm": "2.0.0"
  }
},
```

So you have to download the `runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILAsm` nugget package instead which then contains a `runtimes/win-x64/native/ilasm.exe` file to use.